# Ecommerce thumbnail gallery viewer

Tags: jquery

Usually found on eCommerce websites, I have a main image and about 5 thumbnails. I would like to have the main image change when you click on the smaller thumbnail (different views). Here's an example of what I'm looking for [on this site.](http://www.williams-sonoma.com/products/kitchenaid-pro-line-dicing-food-processor/?pkey=cnew-electrics) I'm looking for a plugin of some sort that will allow me to achieve this.

HTML:

```
<div class="product">
    <img src="pro.jpg">
</div>

<ul class="product-thumb">
    <li><img src="1.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="1.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="1.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: so what is your problem in having that viewer in your  website?    hundreds of jquery viewer there . JFG it

Comment: @zod, sorry... I should have double checked my question. I'm wondering if there is a easy plugin that can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks simple .

You should check in different browsers . especially IE

http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/gallery.html

http://papermashup.com/simple-jquery-gallery/